# Parsing XML using PHP XML Expat Parser

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

Let me preface this with I am NOT a PHP person. My office lost access to our developers recently due to the lockdown on non-essential services, and I need help.
I have an RSS feed generated by our CMS that is being parsed by PHP. The output of the PHP is then generated into HTML by jQuery. What I've found is that if the CMS user forgets to fill out parts of our RSS feed generator, our parser (or jQuery) can't handle the null values. I need some help in figuring out how to error-proof the fields, having some default values substituted if the fields in the XML are null. For example, if the user forgets to input the image, have a default value of "image.png" be substituted, or if they forget the category, have "No category provided." appear.

I've found a method - PHP XML Expat Parser, but I don't know how (and where) to insert it into my code. If someone could start me out with some code, I think I could do the rest of the fields. OR, any help you can provide would be appreciated.

```
          <?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

        //Step 1: process the parameters

        $url   = $_REQUEST['sUrl'];
        $year  = $_REQUEST['getYear'];
        $limit = $_REQUEST['limit'];

        if ($limit == 0) {
           $limit = 1000;
        }

        //Step 2: declare the item class for RSS item array

        class Item
        {
           public $title;
           public $link;
           public $description;
           public $pubDate;
           public $category;
           public $ImgLink;

        }

        //step 3: load the RSS feed into an XML document

        $rss     = simplexml_load_file($url);

        //step 4: initialize the item counter and the item array.

        $items   = 0;
        $outlist = array();

        //step 5: load the RSS item array

        foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item)   {

           //The following lines will format the pubDate into a form
           //that is more amenable for display on web pages.
           //Format example: August 14, 2019

           $date    = date_create($item->pubDate);
           $yr      = date('Y', strtotime($item->pubDate));
           $pubDate = date_format( $date,"F d, Y");

            //The item only gets loaded into the array if the year matches the
            //selected year, and if the array item count has not been reached.

            if ($yr == $year && $items < $limit) {

              //First, a new Item is instantiated based on the class declaration
              //Then we populate the properties with those of the selected item.


               $myItem = new Item();

               $myItem->title       = $item->title;
               $myItem->link        = $item->link;
               $myItem->description = $item->description;
               $myItem->pubDate     = $pubDate;
               $myItem->category    = $item->category;
               $myItem->ImgLink = $item->children('media', True)->content->attributes()->url;


               array_push($outlist,$myItem);

               //increment the item array counter

               $items = $items + 1;
            }
       }
       //step 6: encode the outbound array into JSON format

       $encodedList = json_encode($outlist);

       //final step: return the JSON-encoded array.

       echo $encodedList;

?>
```

Comment: commcordinator did you come along with your task - plz let us know

Comment: Yes, this has been resolved - it's called contracting out the work! hahahaha